# Do not come notification in TFS 2015 in specific collection

Tags: tfs

I created a similar alerts in two collections on the same server. When changing the work item in first collection I receive email, but in the other not.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
[60371] [TEAM FOUNDATION]DefaultCollection:Team Foundation Server 
....
Notification Common Delivery
TF400797: Job extension had an unhandled error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.NotificationJobExtension.SendNotifications(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ISet`1 deliveryTypes)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.NotificationCommonDeliveryJob.DeliverNotifications(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.NotificationDeliveryJobBase.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobRunner.ExecuteJob()
```

Comment: Alert is setting on Team Project level, not collection level. You need to check your alert settings to see whether they apply to the correct Team Projects. If issue persists, you can post your alert setting here.

Comment: The settings are the same for the two projects. http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0117/a8/7e0b8b29815394d9bb3e51fca0414aa8.jpg

Comment: Since you have two same alert setting, and one of them works as expected. It seems there is no issue with your alert setting or SMTP server. Sometimes the notification will delay, you may try later.

Comment: Can you add a little more information to your question? Do you have the two team projects in the same or different collections? If it is two collections, are they then placed on the same server. Do you see an error in the Event Log on the server? And please embed the screenshot from you below comment.

Comment: I tried a few once. It is not in delay.

Comment: Do you have the two team projects in the same or different collections? - Different; Do you see an error in the Event Log on the server? - No  http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0117/a8/7e0b8b29815394d9bb3e51fca0414aa8.jpg

Comment: Please add more details and screenshot to your question.

Comment: In other projects from first collection I receive email, in other projects from second collection not. It turns it depend on the collection.

Comment: Tore Østergaard, What kind of the screenshot you talking about?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the two alert settings. Also, are the collections on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that can cause the problem. There could be a simple typo in the settings of the alert not getting through or the conditions not triggering an alert.

Try

1. Check the Alerts configured to find errors or differences. It would be good to recreate the problematic alert from scratch to ensure that there are no invalid characters in the settings.
2. Given that the collections are placed on different servers, the one not working could have wrong Email Alert Settings. Check the *Team Foundation Server Administration Console under Application Tier* -> *Email Alert Settings*. It should be Enabled and you should be able to *Send Test Email*.
3. Check the [Job Summary](http://localhost:8080/tfs/_oi/_jobMonitoring?_a=summary) (on your TFS server) to see if there are any errors from the job called *Notifications E-Mail Delivery*.
4. Check the Event log (on your TFS server) for errors and warnings around the time the alert should have been triggered.

Comment: 1. I cheked. There is no difference. 2. The collections are placed on same server!  3. i will check up. 4. No errors.

Comment: I added log to above. The DefaultCollection migrated from TFS2008 to TFS2015. Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: Good with the added log! What version of TFS are you running - I seem to recall that there were some problems with notifications in the early version of TFS 2015.

Comment: Version 14.0.23128.0

Comment: That's TFS 2015 RTM, but forgot again that it is working in the other collection on the same server. Have you tried to recreate the alert from scratch to ensure that there is no invalid charcters in there.

Comment: I deleted all created alerts and created them again. Notifications work. The problem most likely occurred during the migration of collection from the old TPS. Thank you all. Special thanks to Tore Østergaard.